# Margin below <TextView/> in <ConstraintLayout/> not working

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

There is a simple layout with `TextView` and `RecyclerView` inside a `ConstraintLayout`.

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clSelectedPatient"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSelectPatient"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lifcare"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rvPatients"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvPatients"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvSelectPatient"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"` below `TextView` is not working.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few mistakes in your layout:

- You use match_parent for width and using match_parent is prohibited for ConstraintLayout subviews.

[Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout - Adjust the view size](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#adjust-the-view-size)

> Note: You cannot use match_parent for any view in a ConstraintLayout.
>   Instead use "match constraints" (0dp)

- In order to display vertical margins properly, you have to define vertical constraints for TextView and RecyclerView.

Your fixed layout code would look like:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/clSelectedPatient"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSelectPatient"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:text="Lifcare"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rvPatients" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvPatients"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvSelectPatient"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is how it looks on device:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add

`app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`

to your RecyclerView